# Bootstrap setting li elements with images inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So basically, I have Screenshots of a function in an App and want to make each Screenshot a li element. Now I want them to display inline which works, but it does not use the space of the whole row and stops with 3 images. Is there a way to make it use the whole row?

**Code Snippet :**

```
<div class="row">
   <h3 id="{{anchor}}" class="headline my-4">{{{title}}}</h3>
       <ul class="d-block">
         {{#each images}}
         <li class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 mb-4 list-inline-item">
             <div class="list-inline-item">
                 <a href="{{{filename}}}.png" data-lightbox="{{{../anchor}}}">
                       <img loading="lazy" data-src="{{{filename}}}.png" class="img-fluid img-shadow lazy" alt="{{{alt}}}" title="{{{alt}}}">
                 </a>
             </div>
         </li>
         {{/each}}
       </ul>
```

**And below is an example!**

[image: example]

Comment: Please use a snippet (`Ctrl+M` or `<>`-button) to show your code. To be [repro] you need to provide an already parsed example that also contains the bootstrap dependency. With the code you provided we can not make the code actually run and reproduce the issue you describe

Answer (score 0):

The padding or more likely the margins might be causing the 4th card to wrap onto the next line. In Bootstrap you can use the following classes for the margins on your `li`'s. If that doesn't work try replacing the M's with P's to alter the padding.

```
m-0 no padding
mx-0 no padding horizontal
my-0 no padding vertical
ms-0 no padding left (start)
me-0 no padding right (end)
```

I suppose it's worth noting that it might be `list-inline-item` that needs an alteration rather than the `li`'s. Try it all :)